# How can I link to a chrome extension in Chrome Web Store when I'm not the developer?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, rss, inline

I've seen the "How to link to chrome extension like Chrome Web Store?" question from Oct. 2011, and I tried to implement it.

However, I realized after some testing that the approach described in answer to that question regarding Inline Installation only works in situations where the original developer of the extension links to his own creation in the Chrome Web Store.

I have a daily podcast that I post to my website, and I want to provide a one-click link for Chrome users to click in order to install The RSS Aggregator extension (which I did NOT develop) directly, so that desktop visitors using Chrome can view my podcast feed in a formatted page rather than just seeing XML code.

Since I'm not the original creator of The RSS Aggregator extension, I don't see a way for me to accomplish this.

For the moment, I'm sending visitors to the Chrome Web Store to install it there, but I've been getting feedback from tech-averse visitors that they can't figure out how to install it without step-by-step installation instructions. Sadly, there are still a lot of people out there who have trouble handling something as simple as adding an extension to their Chrome browsers.

Hence my desire to provide a one-click solution on my site.

Is there a way I can implement a solution on my site?

Comment: If your users can't handle `click this link and then click the button that says 'install'` then I don't see them wanting, understanding or using a browser extension.  I bet they don't even know what a browser is :p

Comment: I agree ... but nevertheless, they exist and they're using a browser, even though they don't understand it.

Comment: I think you've missed my point - If they can't follow those 2 steps then they will not use a browser extension.  Anyway, no, you can't 1-click-install a Chrome extension, for obvious reasons.

Comment: users that "simple" usually use internet explorer or safari, so, win win

Comment: Oh well, I guess I'm just a throwback, because I believe that even "simple" users deserve a good web experience that they can handle, even when they're not using IE or Safari. But thanks anyway. I appreciate you both taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 0):

Never used it before, but maybe this helps you:
https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation#cws-link

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to use. The problem is that it only works if you're the developer and owner of the Chrome extension that you're trying to link to. If you don't own it, then the code from that page fails and generates an error that essentially means that you can't connect.